# fluent nhibernate suppress loading reference

Tags: c#, wcf, nhibernate, poco, lazy-loading

I am using fluent nhibernate to load POCO classes.
I am using ClassMap derivatives to specify mappings.
I am using a configuration like this:

```
.Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings
  .AddFromAssemblyOf<MyClass>()
  .Conventions.Add(FluentNHibernate.Conventions.Helpers.DefaultLazy.Never())
  /** I am using Never() because I have poco classes, not virtual properties **/
)
```

I wish to issue a query that will load up all the child entities with a particular parent id without also populating the parent - the parent is *massive*.

**the query**

How do I issue this query, using criteria or some other mapping or hint to issue the query but not load the parent objects. *I would like finer control over what gets loaded*.
It doesn't have to be the linq provider.

```
var results = _session.Query<Child>().Where(_ => _.Parent.Id == ?).ToList();
```

**the parent**

```
public ParentMap()
{
  Table("Parent");
  Id(x => x.Id).Column("ParentId");
  HasMany(x => x.Children)
    .Table("Children")
    .KeyColumn("ChildId").Inverse()
}
```

**the child**

```
public ChildMap()
{
  Table("Child");
  Id(_ => _.Id).Column("ChildId");
  References(_ => _.Parent).Column("PartyId").LazyLoad(Laziness.NoProxy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just query the child entity:

```
var query = _session.QueryOver<Child>()
   .Where(x=>x.Parent.Id==id)
   .List();
```

Or to have finer control -  use projections and AliasToBean() transformer. Something like:

```
ChildDTO dto = null;
var query = _session.QueryOver<Child>()
.Where(x=>x.Parent.Id==id)
.SelectList(list=>list
   .Select(x=>x.SomeProperty).WithAlias(()=>dto.SomeProperty)
   .Select(x=>x.SomeOtherProperty).WithAlias(()=>dto.SomeOtherProperty))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ChildDTO>())
.List<ChildDTO>();
```

or

```
ChildDTO dto = null;
Child childAlias = null;
var query = _session.QueryOver<Parent>()
.JoinAlias(x=>x.Children, ()=>childAlias, JoinType.InnerJoin)
.Where(x=>x.Id==id)
.SelectList(list=>list
   .Select(x=>childAlias.SomeProperty).WithAlias(()=>dto.SomeProperty)
   .Select(x=>childAlias.SomeOtherProperty).WithAlias(()=>dto.SomeOtherProperty))
.TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<ChildDTO>())
.List<ChildDTO>();
```

Comment: If Child can't be proxied then Parent can't be lazy loaded, so the second option would be required

Comment: Hi, looks like the only solution, my last question though, is can the alias be applied to the original Child instead of ChildDTO. Can you populate the original instance with just the required fields without having to alias each property.